# Using onclick and ontouchend events in Lightning Components

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

I was going through the Lightning Componenet Developer Guide. I noted an interesting point which suggests not to use the onclick and the ontouchend events in the components under Events Anti-Patterns.

> **Don’t Use onclick and ontouchend Events**
>
> You can’t use different
>   actions for `onclick` and `ontouchend` events in a component. The
>   framework translates touch-tap events into clicks and activates any
>   `onclick` handlers that are present.

I want to confirm using both events are not recommended or using any one of them is not recommended.

If it is not recommended to use any one of the events how can I use onclick or touchend events?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By my understanding, this doesn't mean you can't use either; it means you can't use both to perform different actions. You can just use `onclick` and the framework will execute the onclick action when the `ontouchend` event is fired.